# How to configure KODI to run in windowed mode from command line?

Tags: kodi

I am running Kodi via XServer from a 2-monitor remote computer. When Kodi starts, it occupies entire 2 monitor areas and is absolutely useless.

It has a config to run in windowed mode, but how to activate it from command line?

I have edited

```
~/.kodi/userdata/guisettings.xml
```

and changed

```
<screenmode default="true">DESKTOP</screenmode>
```

to

```
<screenmode default="true">WINDOW</screenmode>
```

but it changes back to DESKTOP each run.

How to overcome?

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue. Within the section `<videoscreen>` of file `~/.kodi/userdata/guisettings.xml` you have to change this:

```
<screenmode default="true">DESKTOP</screenmode>
```

To this:

```
<screenmode>WINDOW</screenmode>
```

Start Kodi now and it will be windowed.

Answer (score 0):

In Leia it changed a bit. This will fix it as of today.

Edit `~/.kodi/userdata/guisettings.xml`

Change

```
<setting id="videoscreen.screenmode" default="true">DESKTOP</setting>
```

to

```
<setting id="videoscreen.screenmode" default="false">WINDOW</setting>
```

and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to(instead of) `<setting id="videoscreen.screenmode" default="false">WINDOW</setting>`
There are a setting to choose monitor where Kodi can run fullscreen: (it also available in kodi settings GUI)

> `<setting id="videoscreen.monitor">HDMI-0</setting>`

To find monitor name - run `xrandr` without arguments, it will list all connected and not connected monitors

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it moved again a bit. The change is now under

```
<videoscreen>
```

in:

```
~/.kodi/userdata/guisettings.xml
```

Change

```
<screenmode default="true">DESKTOP</screenmode>
```

to:

```
<screenmode default="false">WINDOW</screenmode>
```